# JavaScript Dynamic JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Need to dynamically select JSON key from the JSON Object itself.

```js
var text = 
    '{"employees":[' + '{"firstName":"lastName", "lastName":"Doe" }]}';  

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var firstName = obj.employees[0].firstName;
var lName = obj.employees[0].firstName;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
     firstName + " " + obj.employees[0].lName;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Output Obtained: "lastName undefined".

Desired Output: "lastName Doe"

Comment: `firstName + " " + lName`

Comment: `"lName"` property does not appear at `JSON`

Comment: Yes lName property is not in JSON, However I am selecting lName on the go i.e lName = "lastName"

Comment: Edit: make code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the code like follows

```
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"lastName","lastName":"Doe" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
var firstName = obj.employees[0].firstName;
var lName = obj.employees[0].firstName;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
firstName + " " + obj.employees[0][lName];
```

Here is the working code:http://jsfiddle.net/NJMyD/5349/